# Android: How Can I put a Dialog box in a loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, dialog, android-dialog

I am trying to make  activity screen in which agreement will be displayed in a dialogue box. 
How can I make the dialog box repeat itself each time user presses "cancel" or "Disagree".
And continue activity on agree. ?

Comment: remove the disagree button and set cancelable on false

Comment: It makes no sense to give the option to cancel when the dialog shows up again. bad idea

Comment: sorry but it makes sense to put. Since User is displayed an agreement if he/she disagrees then application should re-display agreement or may be say like "you must agree " and then re-display .
Thanks for your suggestion though !

Comment: then close the app when not agreed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree that providing the option to "cancel" or "no" while providing no other option but to accept, you could possibly achieve it, using the View's method callOnClick.

This will allow you to trigger the dialog each time the user clicks on No or Cancel. However this would only work with the assumption that you are triggering the original Dialog from a Button since you haven't provided any code to look at (Your activity, its xml layout):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final Context context = this;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a_main_btn);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final View view = v;
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Dialog Title");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Click yes to exit dialog")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            MainActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            view.callOnClick();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what you can do here is:

Inside your for loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaFiles.size(); i++) { 
         ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatActivity.this);
         progressDialog.setMessage("wait sending...");
}
```

call progressDialog.show() and progressDialog.dismiss() where-ever inside loop you want it works fine in loop.

Hope, It will help you!
Thanks